# Print Unicode in a formatter

Tags: unicode, rust, formatting

I need to Print a Unicode Character whose value should not be hard-coded

This is how to Print unicode in General

```
print!("\u{2518}");
```

now the `2518` should not be hard-coded, i need to provide it like that

```
print!("\u{}", 0x2518);
```

I've tried `print!("\u{{}}", 0x2518);` but didn't work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::char::from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html) for this. Because not all values of a `u32` represent valid Unicode Scalar Values, you need to handle an error-case:

```
fn main() {
    let i = 0x2518;
    println!(
        "{}",
        match std::char::from_u32(i) {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => '�',
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: You could also put `char::from_u32(i).unwrap_or('�')`